# Code not finding search bar in web crawler

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, web-crawler

I'm working on a web crawler using Python and BeautifulSoup to scrape a website and extract information from it. However, I'm facing an issue where my code is not able to find the search bar on the website. I would appreciate any help or insights on what might be causing this issue.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/Arsalanmousavi/88849adbdb35d2de6fe78f1b068a7fbf) is the code I'm using. I have already checked the HTML structure of the page and tried different approaches to locate the search bar, but none of them seem to work. The search bar element has the following attributes: class="SearchInput-sc-17srts3-0 eIpOhj" and value="" .
I have also referred to the outer HTML, JS path, and selector of the search bar element, which are as follows:

Outer HTML:

JS path: document.querySelector("#modal-backdrop > div > div > div.SearchModal__SearchInputWrapper-sc-1cbc0b8-6.hcQBmp > input")

Selector: #modal-backdrop > div > div > div.SearchModal__SearchInputWrapper-sc-1cbc0b8-6.hcQBmp > input

I have searched for similar issues on Stack Overflow and Reddit, but I couldn't find a solution that addresses my specific problem. Any suggestions or insights on why my code is not finding the search bar would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help.

Despite my efforts, the code still throws an AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find' error when trying to locate the search bar.

Comment: can you double check if that element actually exists in the source page? You just need to open url in browser, press `Ctrl+U` or `Cmd+U` to open source page

Comment: @DanielSabrel 

Yes. This is the element: 

<input class="SearchInput-sc-17srts3-0 eIpOhj" value="">